# How to include Private Framework in Xcode for iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcode, credit-card

I have to read the credit card details through credit card reader device. For that I need to include `IDTech.Framework` in my application. How to do that?

Comment: I'm just wondering where you get the Credit Card Framework from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just drag the framework into the project navigator.  Alternately you can go to the project build phases, look for the "Link Binary With Libraries" section, and click the "+" on the bottom to add he framework.

Comment: That is the detail.  Drag the framework from Finder into the Xcode project navigator.